# Testing Form Field Widget Type

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing, django-widget

I'm writing tests form a Django model form:

```
class TemplateFieldTextForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TemplateFieldText
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TemplateFieldTextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        field = self.instance.template_field
        label = field.label or var_to_proper(field.identifier)

        if field.input_type == 'text_area':
            self.fields['text'] = forms.CharField(label=label, required=field.required, widget=forms.Textarea)
        else:
            self.fields['text'] = forms.CharField(label=label, required=field.required)
```

I am trying to test that the correct widget for the `text` field gets set, like so:

```
def test_submit_with_char_field(self):
    template_field = mommy.make(TemplateField, label='char_field')
    template_field_text = mommy.make(TemplateFieldText, template_field=template_field,
                                     award_process=self.award_process)
    form_data = {
        'text': 'some text'
    }
    form = TemplateFieldTextForm(form_data, instance=template_field_text)
    self.assertEqual(form.fields['text'].widget.__class__.__name__, 'TextInput')
```

However, the widget seems to always be the `Textarea` widget, rather than the default `TextInput`. When I check the form in the actual rendered template, the form does indeed change as expected. Any ideas as to where I am going wrong in the tests?

Comment: You don't seem to be setting an input_type of 'text_area' anywhere in your test.

Comment: You're right! I'm setting the `label='char_field'` rather than `input_type='char_field`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was setting the incorrect model field value.

```
template_field = mommy.make(TemplateField, label='char_field')
```

should be:

```
template_field = mommy.make(TemplateField, input_type='char_field')
```